# Kill all processes macthing a pattern, ignoring case

Tags: zsh, alias, kill

I want to have an alias to do something like `pkill -f PATTERN` but ignoring the case of the pattern. This is what I have after looking around but it's not working

```
alias pkf="kill `ps ax | grep -i $1 | awk '{ print $2 }'`"
alias pkf9="kill -9 `ps ax | grep -i $1 | awk '{ print $2 }'`"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man pkill` :

```
       -i, --ignore-case
          Match processes case-insensitively
```

So :

```
pkill -fi PATTERN
```

Comment: This is available since procps-ng 3.3.11 on Linux (2015), and earlier still on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also `killall`. The command to ignore case will be:

```
killall -I process_name
```

**WARNING**: this command will work on this way only in Linux. Do not use it in AIX, Solaris, HP-UX!

According to the commit in GitHub `killall` is [21 years old](https://gitlab.com/psmisc/psmisc/-/blob/start/src/killall.c).